# Either to Try and vice versa in Scala

Tags: scala

Are there any conversions from `Either` to `Try` and vice versa in the Scala standard library ? Maybe I am missing something but I did not find them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(NOTICE: this answer applies to Scala 2.11. for more recent versions of Scala, see other answers)

To the best of my knowledge this does not exist in the standard library.  Although an `Either` is typically used with the `Left` being a failure and the `Right` being a success, it was really designed to support the concept of two possible return types with one not necessarily being a failure case.  I'm guessing these conversions that one would expect to exist do not exist because `Either` was not really designed to be a Success/Fail monad like `Try` is.  Having said that it would be pretty easy to enrich `Either` yourself and add these conversions.  That could look something like this:

```
object MyExtensions {
  implicit class RichEither[L <: Throwable,R](e:Either[L,R]){
    def toTry:Try[R] = e.fold(Failure(_), Success(_))
  }
  
  implicit class RichTry[T](t:Try[T]){
    def toEither:Either[Throwable,T] = t.transform(s => Success(Right(s)), f => Success(Left(f))).get
  }  
}

object ExtensionsExample extends App{
  import MyExtensions._
  
  val t:Try[String] = Success("foo")
  println(t.toEither)
  val t2:Try[String] = Failure(new RuntimeException("bar"))
  println(t2.toEither)
  
  val e:Either[Throwable,String] = Right("foo")
  println(e.toTry)
  val e2:Either[Throwable,String] = Left(new RuntimeException("bar"))
  println(e2.toTry)
}
```

Comment: While this is a great solution, as of 2018 `toTry` and `toEither` are included in scala 2.12. It's probably worth adding an edit to the top of you answer.

Answer (score 16):

In Scala 2.12.x Try has a toEither method: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/Try.html#toEither:scala.util.Either[Throwable,T]

Comment: 2.12 also has an Either.toTry method 
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html#toTry(implicitev:<:<[A,Throwable]):scala.util.Try[B]

Answer (score 15):

```
import scala.util.{ Either, Failure, Left, Right, Success, Try }

implicit def eitherToTry[A <: Exception, B](either: Either[A, B]): Try[B] = {
  either match {
    case Right(obj) => Success(obj)
    case Left(err) => Failure(err)

  }
}
implicit def tryToEither[A](obj: Try[A]): Either[Throwable, A] = {
  obj match {
    case Success(something) => Right(something)
    case Failure(err) => Left(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you throwing the error and the catching it with `Try` instead of just wrapping with `Failure`?

Comment: +1 for clear code & pattern matching compared to the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22533154/1707123).

Answer (score 7):

The answer depends on how to convert the `Failure` to `Left` (and vice versa). If you don't need to use the details of the exception, then `Try` can be converted to `Either` by going the intermediate route of an `Option`:

```
val tried = Try(1 / 0)
val either = tried.toOption.toRight("arithmetic error")
```

The conversion the other way requires you to construct some Throwable. It could be done like this:

```
either.fold(left => Failure(new Exception(left)), right => Success(right))
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Scala 2.13 (and hence Scala 3) the standard library supports both conversions. The conversion from `Either` to `Try` in the Scala standard library is documented [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/Either.html#toTry(implicitev:A%3C:%3CThrowable):scala.util.Try%5BB%5D), and vice versa is documented [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/Try.html#toEither:scala.util.Either%5BThrowable,T%5D).